# Given the area between two values on a normal distribution, how would you use the inverse normal?

Tags: normal-distribution

> Given that $X$~$N(10, 0.5^2)$, find $c$ such that:
>   $$P(12.6-2c < x < 11.9+c)=0.2$$

I can solve simpler problems of this sort, for example I can solve:

$P(10-c < x < 10+c)=0.2$ but only because the two end areas are equal. I wanted to know if there was an easy way to calculate $c$ in my first example.

I am aware that you can integrate the equation of the normal curve using the error function, but that is way beyond my understanding at the moment.

Comment: I don't see any easy way in this asymmetric case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is easier than it appears at first glance.

With a little algebra, 
$$12.6-2c < x < 11.9+c$$
if and only if
$$5.2-4c < \frac{x-10}{0.5} < 3.8+2c$$
and $(x-10)/0.5$ has a $N(0,1)$ distribution.  So we want to solve 
$$\Phi(3.8+2c)-\Phi(5.2-4c) = 0.2$$
for $c$, where $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative standard normal distribution.

At $c=0$, the left-hand side of the equation is essentially $1-1=0$, while for large $c$ it becomes $1-0=1$, so we expect a positive root.  But for $c>0$,  $\Phi(3.8+2c) \approx 1$, so we can replace our equation with
$$1-\Phi(5.2-4c) = 0.2$$
I'm guessing you can probably take it from here.

Comment: Yep, I get a solution of c=1.0896 (4 decimal places). However I am unsure about the step where you say:Φ(3.8+2)−Φ(5.2−4)=0.2

Comment: @Jamminermit: $\Phi(3.8+2c)-\Phi(5.2-4c)$ is the area under the normal curve between  $5.2-4c$ and $3.8+2c$.

Comment: Ok, I see that now thanks.